# C# Regex Replace expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, replace

I have a string like this: "programming is my passion, I love programs"

Now I need to change this using Regex Replace. Each word that contains expression "program" should be switched to:

`<a href="http://codeguru.pl" title="programming">programming</a>`

Any help will be grateful.

Comment: Have a look at the method definition for [`Regex.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.100).aspx) for a start.

Comment: Do you really want "is my passion" to be part of the replacement for "program"?

Comment: Would you be interested in having an output of this form? `<a href="http://codeguru.pl" title="programming">programming</a> is my passion, I love <a href="http://codeguru.pl" title="programs">programs</a>`

Comment: Thank You for Your responses. I tried to use that: `Regex.Replace(string, "program*\s", "")`, but I don't know what should be in 3rd part. ~Barmar, thanks, my fault.

Comment: The third part is the string you are replacing `"program*\s"` with. In your case it'll be the anchor tag.

Comment: ~Srinivas, yes, that will solve this example, but I need a unique solution

Comment: Why are the two answers that have been provided not good enough? What is a "unique solution"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner should suffice:

```
new Regex(@"\b\w*program\w*\b").Replace("programming is my passion, I love programs", @"<a href=""http://codeguru.pl"" title=""programming"">programming</a>");
```

where `\b\w*program\w*\b` matches any word that contains `program`.

If you want to change the link's text according to the matched word, use the back-reference:

```
new Regex(@"(\b\w*program\w*\b)").Replace("programming is my passion, I love programs", @"<a href=""http://codeguru.pl"" title=""programming"">$1</a>");
```

This version adds brackets around the pattern, and use `$1`(instead of hard-coded string "`programming`") to refer the matched word.
Now the output will be:

```
<a href="http://codeguru.pl" title="programming">programming</a> is my passion, I love <a href="http://codeguru.pl" title="programming">programs</a>
```

Comment: Thank You for that solution, it helped me.
But what should I change in code, if I want this output:
`<a href="http://codeguru.pl" title="programming">programming</a> is my passion, I love <a href="http://codeguru.pl" title="programming">programs</a>` ?

Comment: @Will you can take use of back-reference in regular expression. I have updated it in the answer.

Comment: thank You very much, You helped me immensely. All the best, regards

Comment: @Will My pleasure. One suggestion for you: to avoid downvote of your question, you could make your question more explicit to reflect your specific requirement as that in your last comment.

Answer (score 3):

[String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) is better bet here.

```
var input = "programming is my passion, I love programs";
var replacefrom = "program";
var tobereplaced =@"<a href=""http://codeguru.pl"" title=""programming"">programming</a> is my passion";

var output = input.Replace(replacefrom, tobereplaced)
```

[Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx)

```
Regex regex = new Regex("program");
var outputRegex = regex.Replace(input, tobereplaced); // input, tobereplaced from above snipped
```

**output**

```
<a href="http://codeguru.pl" title="programming">programming</a> is my passionming is my passion, I love <a href="http://codeguru.pl" title="programming">programming</a> is my passions
```

Comment: A fine example of garbage in, garbage out (the output text, not your answer).

Answer (score 0):

The solution..

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+|\\W)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher("programming is my passion, I love programs");
    while (m.find())
    {
    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(program)");
    Matcher m1 = pattern1.matcher(m.group());

    if(m1.find())
        System.out.print(m.group().replace(m.group(), "<a href="+"http://codeguru.pl"+" title="+"programming"+">programming</a>"));
    else
        System.out.print(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
<a href=http://codeguru.pl title=programming>programming</a> is my passion, I love <a href=http://codeguru.pl title=programming>programming</a>
```

Comment: That's not the same output as stated in the question. Nor does it match what your code will do.

Comment: Yes, it works. But If i would like a unique solution, e. x.:
`<a href="http://codeguru.pl" title="programming"> word that contains the expression program</a> ?

Comment: not clear about your unique solution,it would be better if you give a complete example of your input and output(what exactly you want) just like as above your question..then i would update my answer

Comment: Thank You, it helped me. By unique solution I mean output: `<a href="http://codeguru.pl" title="programming">programming</a> is my passion, I love <a href="http://codeguru.pl" title="programming">programs</a>`: all the words with the expression program stay, and links to the page